# Append to li with a different color

Tags: jquery

I want to append to a list and i want that to be a different color. So first li should be black and the second one should be in a different color..

What I've tried:

```
$('ul', '.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"]').html('<li>' + resp.failedMessage + '</li>');
$('ul', '.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"]').append('<li>' + resp.successMessage + '</li>').css('color', '#438D80');
```

The color gets added to the ul instead of the li, (both li's gets a new color). How can this be solved?

Comment: You simply have to create a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the color to the `ul` not to the `li`

```
$('ul', '.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"]').html('<li>' + resp.failedMessage + '</li>');

$('<li>' + resp.successMessage + '</li>').appendTo('.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"] ul').css('color', '#438D80');
```

`.append()` returns the element to which the new element is appended, not the newly created element. You can use `.appendTo()` as given above

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('ul', '.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"]')
    .html('<li>' + resp.failedMessage + '</li>');

    var liTwo = $( '<li>' ).text( resp.successMessage ).css( 'color', '#438D80' );

    $('ul', '.validation-summary-errors[data-valmsg-summary="true"]')
    .append( liTwo );
```